# taking variables from one function to use in another function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

i'm creating a game in javascript for college and i have a button to call a function but i need it to include variables from another function

if i put the function inside the other function where the variables are the button doesn't call it

is there a way of doing this or to get the variables that were created in the first function and use them in the second function

it is a simple maths game where you get a random number a random sum and another random number
(i.e. 5+7, 4*3, 2/6, etc,)

so i've got a function to show the random number using

```
var ranNum1a=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
```

i need the other function to check the users answer but i need to know what the random number was from the other function

Comment: Use global variables. This is the simplest way.

Comment: if i declare the variables outside the function it will be the same random numbers for the next question when it calls the function again that is the problem i am having

Comment: I don't really understand where's your problem. Maybe you should paste some code.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Note that there is almost *never* any reason to use truly global variables as various people seem to be suggesting (though you might use variables that are global to *your code*).

Comment: Take a look at http://requirejs.org to organize your files. It allows you to use module dependencies quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make those variables global
example:

```
var myValue;
function setValue()
{
    myValue = "test";
}

function getValue()
{
    alert(window.myValue); // yup, it's "test"
}
```

[source..](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable)

Comment: *yup, it's "test"* Not necessarily. Not if you don't call `setValue`.

Comment: [Do *not* make those variables global](http://weblogs.asp.net/wallen/archive/2003/05/08/6750.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For simplest case, passing variables to another function might be the best approach to this problem.

Here is an illustration:

```
function f1(var1, var2) {
    //do you stuff then pass the variable to another function
    f2(var1, var2);
}

function f2(v1, v2) {
    // here v1 will get the value from var1 and v2 from var2 if passed from within the function f1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ranNum1a;
function show() {
  ranNum1a = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  // show it
}

function check() {
  if (ranNum1a == 42) {
    alert("Ok");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be extremely helpful in relation to the original question:

Return the value you wish to use in functionOne, then call functionOne within functionTwo and place the result into a fresh var. This should enable you to use the var declared in functionOne, within functionTwo.

```
function functionOne() {
  var variableThree = 3;
  return variableThree;
}

function functionTwo() {
  var variableOne = 1;
  var var3 = functionOne();

  var result = var3 - variableOne;

  console.log(variableOne);
  console.log(var3);
  console.log('functional result: ' + result);
}

functionTwo();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function function1() {
            var a = 1;
            localStorage.setItem("var1", a);
            alert("Function1 value of a: " + a); 
        }

        function function2() {
            var a = localStorage.getItem("var1");
            alert("Function2 value of a: " + a); 
        }
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Here the variable x is declared globally so that it can be used in all the functions

The same approach can be used in python also but inside a function if you want to change the variable then you have to declare it with global keyword

```html
<!-- First declare the variable -->
   <script>
   var x;
   function something(){
      var x = document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML
   }
   function other(){
      document.write(x);
   `you can use x here x is same as document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML`
   
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).